# what is url double escaping?

Tags: java, url-encoding

I am looking to double escape a url string in java. I don't know what is meant by double escaping a url. I also request some one to post sample java code that I can use to do this.

thank you.

Comment: why are you looking to do something if you don't know what it means?

Comment: you are not saying the purpose and your post is not understandable. -1

Comment: rephrasing the question: How can I double escape a url string in java?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How can I double escape a url string in java

The simple answer is by escaping it, and then escaping it a second time.

Assuming that "escaping" really means URL encoding, then:

```
String input = ...
String output = URLEncoder.encode(URLEncoder.encode(input, "UTF-8"), "UTF-8");
```

However, the correct solution is probably more complicated than that ... *depending on what you are going to do with the result*.  For instance, if you URL encode a complete URL string (once or twice), it is no longer a valid URL.

If you took the time to explain the context, we'd be in a better position to give you a solution that might actually work for you.